# Optimal constants for $m_s(a^s+b^s)\leq (a+b)^s \leq M_s(a^s+b^s)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

It is well known that for $a, b \in [0,\infty)$ and $s \geq 0$ there exists positive constants $m_s$ and $M_s$ such that $$m_s(a^s+b^s)\leq (a+b)^s \leq M_s(a^s+b^s).$$

I would like to know if is possible to determine (explicitly) the optimal constants $m_s$ and $M_s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that $m_s=\min\{1,2^{s-1}\}$ and $M_s=\max\{1,2^{s-1}\}$ for $s>0$. Indeed, one can check that the equality occurs either for $a=b=1$ or for $a=1$ and $b=0$.

One can prove these by using convexity/concavity alone. Let me illustrate it for the case $0<s\leq1$.

By concavity of $f(x)=x^s$, we have
$$
\frac{a^s+b^s}2\leq\big(\frac{a+b}2\big)^s
$$
yielding
$$
2^{s-1}(a^s+b^s)\leq(a+b)^s.
$$
Another use of concavity gives
$$
\frac{a}{a+b}(a+b)^s\leq a^s
\qquad\textrm{and}\qquad
\frac{b}{a+b}(a+b)^s\leq b^s.
$$
Summing these two then we get
$$
(a+b)^s\leq a^s+b^s.
$$

The case $s>1$ is exactly the same, with concavity replaced by convexity.

Comment: I didn't understand the idea, could you give more details? Please

Comment: @VictorHugo: Updated

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be $\frac{b}{a+b}(a+b)^s \leq b^s$, in the fourth row from the bottom to up, right?

Comment: @VictorHugo: Yes!